# how to connect to other page using iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, bugzilla

Is it possible to give link to buzilla login page from our own openlayers map? Like by using iframe button is it possible to link ?

```
var html = "<div class=iframelink ><iframe id=bugfile style='display:none' src='https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi'></iframe></div>";
$(html).appendTo(body);
```

Is this code correct?

Comment: Why not try and see if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. If you will take a look at response headers of that page, you will see there a header like this: `X-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN` which means that it could not be used in iframe located on another website.

Details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Comment: is it possible to change that x-frame-options somehow?

Comment: @SSS I'm afraid no. That is something you can set on your server to avoid others including your pages into their sites. mozilla does not want their bugzilla site to be used in iframe and I'm afraid you can't change that.